# Read specific node in a JSON string as raw JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

Lets say I have a model:

```
public class Node<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I serialize a node of `int[]` resulting in:

```
{"value":[1,2,3]}
```

I now want to deserialize it to: `Node<string>` hence treat it as a chunk of JSON:

```
node.Value == "[1,2,3]"
```

I now I can use a custom `JsonConverter` that e.g. uses `JToken.ReadFrom` and then do a `ToString` on it. This, however, makes formatting etc. break.

I can also create a new `JsonWriter` and use it like this in my `Converter`:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (var wo = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (var w = new JsonTextWriter(wo))
        {
            w.WriteToken(reader, true);
        }    
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The issue I have with this solution is that it will create writers for each property marked with the converter...

The third solution would then be to traverse the graph myself and reuse a writer etc.

Which is the recommended (most effective) solution to deserialize certain nodes in a JSON string, to raw JSON? Note, it will be many items in the JSON result, so there isn't just one object that will have this node.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us some more context on what problem you're really trying to solve with all of this, i.e. why do you need to keep partial JSON in your model?  Also, what do you mean by "This, however, makes formatting etc. break."  You kind of gloss over this point; can you give an example?  Lastly, in the part where you show a portion of your converter, you say that you don't want to create a new writer each time.  Why is this such a big issue?

Comment: @brian: formatting as the option in Json.Net since that's be default associated with the serializer, however, you could use the serializer to deserialize the token to work around this. The case is simple, e.g. `{\"value\":[1,2,3]}` should be deserialized to a model with `string` and not `int` (read above). If you go the more manual route with more "manual" use of `JsonTextReader` and `JsonTextWriter` instead of converter as above, you get better perf.

Answer (score 1):

Json.NET parses JSON to tokens (object start, property, string, etc) and the serializer then reads those tokens to construct an object. There is no way to capture raw incoming text and preserve formatting exactly.

The closets functionality to that is having a JToken property which will end up with an object representing the raw JSON. You can then call ToString() on it but the exact formatting will be lost.

If you want to write JSON in a specific way then the contents of a JRaw property will be written exactly as supplied.

**[Serialize Raw JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeRawJson.htm)**

Comment: Thanks, ended up in using a custom JsonConverter on those specific properties. The converter checks for `string, string[]` or other. If `string`, it reads out the node and child structure using Writer.WriteToken(reader, true). If `string[]` it pretty much does the same thing, except using the reader to read from the underlying array and reusing a writer and a StringBuilder to build up an "array" of strings. The Writer gets the setting according to the serializer.